# My CIN command skips input entirely? I've tried everything

Tags: c++, input, cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

     int a, b;
     int I, P;
     unsigned int x;
     unsigned int y;
     int n, m;
     unsigned int X, O;

     int tictac[3][3] = {
        {1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1} ,
        {1, 1, 1} };

      cout << "Player 1, enter X or O:" << endl;
      cin >> a;

      while (a == X);
      {
          cout << "Now, fill in the desired coordinated in a 3x3 square, a[x][y]"    << endl;
          cout << "Enter 'x' in [x]" << endl;
          cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
          cin >> x;
          cout << "Enter 'y' in [y]" << endl;
          cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
          cin >> y;

          tictac[x][y] == X;
      }

}
```

I'm writing a program that lets 2 players play tictactoe on a 3x3 grid, and the rest of the "CIN" commands refuses to accept an input.

I've tried changing the "CIN" commands to:

```
getline (cin, x)
getline (cin, y)
```

Tried changing the variables from (Unsigned int) to (Signed int), and use the cin.ignore() commands, yet the problem remains.

Comment: I am afraid `a == X` is not what you expect it to be. `X` is not initialized, so there are high chances that you never enter the while loop.

Comment: @OpenTheCSV You're not compiling with that many warnings enabled, are you? Your compiler could point out a few problems with your code if you'd only let it.

Comment: @OpenTheCSV And why does it tell the user to enter a letter when you're reading into an `int`?!

Comment: @Biffen good point, I fixed it to be "Char X, O = 0;" instead of just "Unsigned int X, O;" but its still broken. Also how do I let my compiler run with most warnings enabled?

Comment: @OpenTheCSV That would depend on the compiler. Surely it would have some kind of documentation. If not then Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 unsigned int X, O;

 int tictac[3][3] = {
    {1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1} ,
    {1, 1, 1} };

  cout << "Player 1, enter X or O:" << endl;
  cin >> a;

  while (a == X);
```

In that last line, `X` has not been initialized, so you're comparing `a`'s value to nothing in particular. Also, the semi-colon at the end makes the loop repeat an empty statement.

```
      tictac[x][y] == X;
```

This is a comparison whose result you throw away. Use `=` for assignment.